# Access to static variable in class with multiple generic types

Tags: c#, generics

I have an `Entity` abstract generic class which main characteristic is that it can be grouped with other **instances of different implementations** of this same class, around a common "group id".

For example, a `MoveBehaviour` and `FlyBehaviour` can implement `Entity` so two given instances of these classes could be assigned to a given `Person` instance and `FlyBehaviour` could look up its corresponding `MoveBehaviour` easily.

One can argument I'm killing OOP so I should go home and never ever touch a computer again, but let's have this discussion some other day.

This is my attempt:

```
public abstract class Entity<T> where T : Entity<T>
{
    private int groupId;
    protected static Dictionary<int, T> entityMap = new Dictionary<int, T>();

    public Entity(int groupId)
    {
        this.groupId = groupId;
        entityMap.Add(groupId, (T) this);
    }

    public T2 GetCoEntity<T2>() where T2 : Entity<T2>
    {
        return T2.entityMap[groupId];
    }
}
```

The compiler complains it doesn't know what `entityMap` is and I don't understand why.

Comment: did you try with return entityMap[groupId]; instead of return T2.entityMap[groupId];

Comment: but that would return an instance of `T`, not `T2`, right?

Comment: `T2.entityMap` trying to access protected member of another type, which is not allowed. Even `T2` derives from `Entity<T>` it still considered as separate class and you are not able access it's protected members.

Comment: @Fabio It doesn't work if it's public too. And `entityMap` is a member of their base type.

Comment: Are you sure this would be correct signature `public int GetCoEntity<int>() where int : Entity<int>`?

Comment: @StephenKennedy The OP is trying to access the static member, thus does not need an instance.

Comment: @StephenKennedy Doesn't have to be `public` just has to use `Entity<T2>` since `T2` is just a generic type and you need the actual class type to access static member.

Comment: @Fabio `int` cannot be the generic type because it does not implement `Entity<int>` this only works for classes like `public class MyClass : Entity<MyClass>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the class type to the call:

```
return Entity<T2>.entityMap[groupId];
```

**EDIT**

Why is this needed?

[Static methods/properties are not virtual](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/330316/why-shouldnt-static-methods-be-able-to-be-overrideable) so the `entityMap` object does not exist on `T2` as it is derived from `Entity<T2>`. You need to use the base type when using the static property

Comment: Why? Isn't `T2` `Entity<T2>`??

Comment: @Roberto I had to get my head around this but I've updated the answer - there are other references about static methods and properties but I've added the one I think is relevant. Feel free to point out a better one if you find one :-)